# iOS/cocoapods duplicate interface definition for ProtocolBuffers class

Tags: ios, cocoapods, protocol-buffers

I have 4 projects in my workspace, 3 static libraries and 1 app. And I use protocolBuffers for 1 lib project and app project, the pod setting like below:

```
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

target 'MyApp' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
  pod 'AFNetworking', "~> 3.0"
  pod 'HTMLReader', "~> 0.9.4"
  pod 'FCModel', "~> 0.9.0"
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack', "~> 2.0.0"
  pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
  pod 'ProtocolBuffers', "~> 1.9.10"
  pod 'FXBlurView', "1.6.4"
  pod 'NJKWebViewProgress', "0.2.3"
  pod 'SDWebImage', "3.7.5"
  pod 'PureLayout', "3.0.1"
  pod 'SpinKit', "1.2.0"
  pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', "1.2.11"
  pod 'JDStatusBarNotification', "1.5.3"
  pod 'MSDynamicsDrawerViewController'
end

target 'UIFoundation' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  project 'UIFoundation/UIFoundation.xcodeproj'
end

target 'DataFoundation' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  project 'DataFoundation/DataFoundation.xcodeproj'
  pod 'ProtocolBuffers', "~> 1.9.10"
end

target 'CommonFoundation' do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
  project 'CommonFoundation/CommonFoundation.xcodeproj'
  pod 'AFNetworking', "~> 3.0"
  pod 'RNCryptor', "~> 3.0.1"
  pod 'HTMLReader', "~> 0.9.4"
  pod 'FCModel', "~> 0.9.0"
  pod 'CocoaLumberjack', "~> 2.0.0"
  pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
end
```

The '**pod install**' response success without any warning or error, but the Xcode response error '**duplicate interface definition for ProtocolBuffers class**' when I build my projects:
[image]
[image]

Anyone who knows what is the problem of my setting? Below is my work environment:

```
cocoapods version: 1.0.1
ProtocolBuffers version: 1.9.10
Xcode version: 7.3;
MAC system version: 10.11.5
```

p.s.: I've build success with the same projects and pod file before 2 month ago, I did not change any settings for. On today morning, I got some error messages from terminal when I run 'pod install' in my project, so I've update the 'HomeBrew', 'ruby', 'gems', 'cocoaPods' for my MAC.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should check link binary with libraries section for possible duplicate pod framework.Also using "pod deintegrate" to sterilize project from cocoapod files and creating it from scratch may help you